# Get own facebook page feed using php

Tags: php, facebook

I'm trying to get my own facebook page feed and register a wordpress post for every post on my facebook page. I got it working, but access token keeps expiring. I looked allover and still can't find a definitive answer about this.
Is it still possible to auto generate an access token using php? I have my facebook app id and secret. If so, how can I do this? Preferably without SDK.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Extended Page Token: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension

It is valid for at least 60 days though, and you cannot auto generate it. After that time, you may have to generate it again. Earlier, it was valid forever - until you changed your Facebook password or invalidate the App Secret.